# "О котором речь" без указательного местоимения: формальная допустимость

Tags: пунктуация

> Спустя полчаса притормозил красный лиаз. Все автобусы проезжали мимо, а этот, о котором речь, путников подобрал.

Тут всё понятно. А если:

> Спустя полчаса притормозил красный лиаз. Все автобусы проезжали мимо, а о котором речь — путников подобрал.

**Допустимо ли такое формально?**

Comment: Интересный вопрос (плюсик от меня)!  Странно, что нет голосов, ответов или даже  комментариев.  А вы какой оценки  ждете, что значит "формально"? Думаете, что это можно отнести к нейтральной речи и в синтаксисе описаны такие конструкции? Там, кстати есть еще такая оценка: «допускается в качестве разговорного», а иногда вариант относят к некорректному.

Comment: Как вы сами оцените его, хотя бы чисто на слух?  Может, это просторечие или, напротив, новое направление в грамматике? Меня же вариант заинтересовал, я даже вспомнила стихи одного деревенского поэта. "Свидание" Я записочку послал, Ждал весь год... О которой я мечтал – Не придет…  Очень лирические и трогательные стихи, но есть вопрос насчет правильности…  Вот что ему ответить?   :))   Или в вашем предложении другая конструкция?

Comment: @Sharon под "формально" я имею в виду то, как расценивать в моём случае конструкцию "о котором речь". Ведь чтобы говорить о нормальности, надо сперва разобрать предложение. // Ваш пример со стихом — да, подобен, на мой взгляд. Мне интересно ещё, как мой вариант вообще звучит: я хочу использовать его в довольно нейтральном художественном тексте, и если такая фишка воспринимается как прям совсем дЯревня, то не канает.

Comment: Ну что я могу вам пока коротко ответить.  Под стандарт точно не подходит (я посмотрела).  Тогда, скорее всего, это не тема СПП с придаточными определительными или местоименно-определительными, тем более что это часть ССП, а не самостоятельное предложение.  На слух  просторечием не кажется, больше похоже на  новый авторский грамматический стиль. А вот насколько новый – не знаю. Поэтому мне и интересно, как он «звучит». Может, еще кто подскажет, примеры приведет.

Comment: У меня есть еще такая идея: может это описательный оборот в роли подлежащего. Можно, например, сказать: Которые тут временные должны уйти,  кончилось ваше время. У вас:  Все автобусы проезжали мимо, а о котором речь — путников подобрал.

Comment: @Sharon да, на описательный оборот похоже. Раз не звучит просторечно, то, наверное, использую, если не сейчас, то вообще. Я люблю такие странные грамматические построения)

Comment: Ну, это мое мнение, хотелось бы еще кого послушать. А вы, значит, художественные тексты пишете, а мне не рассказываете... :)

Comment: @Sharon пока рассказывать не о чем :) Всё на уровне экспериментов. Если что-нибудь интересное получится — непременно попрошу вас быть моей... нет, это из другой оперы... быть моим бета-ридером: это куда серьёзнее!